# Pandas P&L rollup to the next business day

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime, quantitative-finance

I'm having a hard time trying to do this efficiently. I have some stocks and daily P&L info in a dataframe. In reality, I have millions of rows of data so efficiency matters a lot!
The Dataframe looks like :

```
-------------------------------
| Date       | Security | P&L |
-------------------------------
| 2016-01-01 | AAPL     | 100 |
-------------------------------
| 2016-01-02 | AAPL     | 200 |
-------------------------------
| 2016-01-03 | AAPL     | 300 |
-------------------------------
| 2016-01-04 | AAPL     | -200 |
-------------------------------
```

All, I want to do is roll the P&L over to the next business day (exclude all US holidays and weekends)
So, the resultant Dataframe looks like this:

```
-------------------------------
| Date       | Security | P&L |
-------------------------------
| 2016-01-04 | AAPL     | 400 |
-------------------------------
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve this. I do have thousands of securities and over 5 yrs of data to process so brute force can't work, unfortunately!

Thanks in advance and highly appreciate any pointers on this!

Comment: Have you got list of days to drop?

Comment: @ansev you can use `weekday` and this library [holidays](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays)

Comment: You might consider using `dask` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create the DataFrame of business dates then `merge_asof`. Then we can group on this to get the sums.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
date_min = '2015-01-01'
date_max = '2016-12-31'

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(date_min, date_max).tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bdate': pd.bdate_range(date_min, date_max, 
                                            holidays=holidays, freq='C')})

res = pd.merge_asof(df, df2, left_on='Date', right_on='bdate', direction='forward')
#        Date Security  P&L      bdate
#0 2016-01-01     AAPL  100 2016-01-04
#1 2016-01-02     AAPL  200 2016-01-04
#2 2016-01-03     AAPL  300 2016-01-04
#3 2016-01-04     AAPL -200 2016-01-04

res.groupby(['Security', 'bdate'])['P&L'].sum()
#Security  bdate     
#AAPL      2016-01-04    400
```

Comment: It should. It will be a 1:1 merge, bringing the closest business day in the future, so there's no worry about changing the shape. Just make sure to specify the proper min and max dates to encompass the full dataset.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
import numpy as np

date_min = '2015-01-01'
date_max = '2016-12-31'

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(date_min, date_max).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(date_min, date_max)})
df["Security"] ="APPL"
df["P&L"] = np.random.randint(-1000, 1000, len(df))

df[~df["Date"].isin(holidays)].groupby("Security")\
                              .agg({"Date":"max",
                                    "P&L":"sum"})\
                              .reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks...I think this would do it

Comment: This should work without change in dask if you want to run it faster. I migh suggest you that if this is a daily job you should consider other approaches.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware about dask...It looks really promising....Going to experiment with it! Thanks